# regex to extract data between quotes

Tags: python, regex

As title says string is `'="24digit number"'` and I want to extract number between `""` (example: `="000021484123647598423458"` should get me `'000021484123647598423458'`).

There are answers that answer how to get  data between `"` but in my case I also need to confirm that `="` exist without capturing (there are also other `"\d{24}"` strings, but they are for other stuff) it.

I couldn't modify these answers to get what I need.

My latest regex was `((?<=\")\d{24}(?=\"))` and string is `="000021484123647598423458"`.

UPDATE: I think I will settle with pattern `r'^(?:\=\")(\d{24})(?:\")'` because I just want to capture digit characters.

`word = '="000021484123647598423458"'
pattern = r'^(?:\=\")(\d{24})(?:\")'
match = re.findall(pattern, word)[0]`

Thank you all for suggestions.

Comment: Please share your code. Tried `re.findall(r'="(\d{24})"', s)`? If your strings always look like `="`, then digits and end with `"`, it can be done even easier. Are you extracting multiple matches from a long string? Please provide examples.

Comment: What regex function have you tried? findall? match? search? Please be specific with what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I seriously hope you initialised `text` as `'"000021484123647598423458"' `and not `"000021484123647598423458"`...

Comment: You want `int` with `24` digits or `string` with `24` digits.You can use `b=a.zfill(24)` for doing this operation.You can do this type of operation without using `regex`.If you think like me.

Answer (score 2):

You could have it like:

```
=(['"])(\d{24})\1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Jie1hr/2/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

string = '="000021484123647598423458"'

rx = re.compile(r'''=(['"])(\d{24})\1''')
print(rx.search(string).group(2))
# 000021484123647598423458
```

Comment: You can also ensure that the trailing quote matches…

Comment: Yes, but your previous solution with look-behind could be improve with look-after. Even if it is un usual for beginner.

Comment: I have hallucinations: the OP already posted this kind of solution.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE OP just forgot to add a `=` because most probably took the `=` that is part of a positive lookbehind for a literal `=`. The question is rather off-topic all in all.

Answer (score 0):

Any one of the following works:

```
>>> st = '="000021484123647598423458"'
>>> import re 
>>> re.findall(r'".*\d+.*"',st)
['"000021484123647598423458"']
```

or

```
>>> re.findall(r'".*\d{24}.*"',st)
['"000021484123647598423458"']
```

or

```
>>> re.findall(r'"\d{24}"',st)
['"000021484123647598423458"']
```